# Bug in using listing, an "é" pop at the first line

Tags: bugs

Currently using *\usepackage{listings}* and since I did not have any trouble. But my last two insertion I have a bug : an "é" is inserted at the first line.
I am using Overleaf and here is the context :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Ajout de code dans latex
\usepackage{listings}
%change the caption "Listing x" to "Algorithme x"
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{}
%And to color the code
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\lstdefinestyle{Langage_C}{
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        keywordstyle=\color{myblue}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{mygreen}\ttfamily,
        frame=single, 
        breaklines=true,
        numbers=left, 
        frame=single,
        extendedchars=\true,  
        breaklines,
        rulecolor=\color{black},
}
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=64,style = Langage_C, numbers = none]{4_main.c}

\end{document}
```

Here the command I use to insert the code (the source is already included in the files) :

Here is the code source screened with the number of lines I use as a landmark :

```
#include <asf.h>
#include "Constants.h"
#include "Calcul_Gabarit.h"

struct tc_module tc_instance4;
struct tc_module tc_instance6;
struct dac_module dac_instance;

int Etat = Marche; // Définition de Etat (Marche = 1)
int Vpalier = 5000; //Vient du LIN par la suite

void configure_tc4(void); // TC4 configuration procedure
void configure_tc6(void); // TC6 configuration procedure
void configure_tc_callbacks(void); // Configure callback procedure
void configure_port_pins(void); //Configure port pins
void tc_callback_LEDBlink(struct tc_module *const module_inst); // Callback procedure
void configure_dac(void);
void configure_dac_channel(void);
int Calcul_Gabarit (int Etat , int Vpalier);

typedef enum {Repos, Acceleration, VitesseConstante, Deceleration}State;
    State state= Repos;
int Vconsigne=0;
int Temps=0;
int i = 0;//Used for led blinking counter

void configure_port_pins(void){
    struct port_config config_port_pin;

    port_get_config_defaults(&config_port_pin);         // pin default configuration
    config_port_pin.direction=PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT;      // change direction from input(default) to output
    port_pin_set_config(EXT2_PWM_0_PIN,&config_port_pin);   // Apply configuration to pin PB12
}

void configure_tc4(void){
    struct tc_config config_tc4;
    tc_get_config_defaults(&config_tc4);
    config_tc4.counter_size    = TC_COUNTER_SIZE_16BIT;
    config_tc4.wave_generation = TC_WAVE_GENERATION_MATCH_FREQ;
    config_tc4.counter_16_bit.compare_capture_channel[0] = 7999;

    config_tc4.pwm_channel[0].enabled = true; // PWM output is enabled for channel 0
    config_tc4.pwm_channel[0].pin_out = EXT2_PWM_0_PIN; // W0 signal on TC4
    config_tc4.pwm_channel[0].pin_mux = EXT2_PWM_0_MUX; // Mux setting for W0 signal on TC4 (PB12)

    tc_init(&tc_instance4, TC4, &config_tc4);
    tc_enable(&tc_instance4);
}

void configure_tc6(void){
    struct tc_config config_tc6;
    tc_get_config_defaults(&config_tc6);
    config_tc6.counter_size    = TC_COUNTER_SIZE_16BIT;
    config_tc6.wave_generation = TC_WAVE_GENERATION_MATCH_PWM ;
    config_tc6.counter_16_bit.compare_capture_channel[0] = PWM_CC0; //Defines the period of PWM signal
    //config_tc6.counter_16_bit.compare_capture_channel[1] = Vconsigne*799/VpalierMax; //Initial value, not compulsory

    config_tc6.pwm_channel[1].enabled = true; // PWM output is enabled for channel 1
    config_tc6.pwm_channel[1].pin_out = EXT1_PWM_1_PIN; // W1 signal on TC6 (cf datasheet)
    config_tc6.pwm_channel[1].pin_mux = EXT1_PWM_1_MUX; // Mux setting for W1 signal on TC6 (PB03)

    tc_init(&tc_instance6, TC6, &config_tc6);
    tc_enable(&tc_instance6);
}

void configure_dac(void){//Digital to Analog Converter
    //Setup is similar to TC setup
    struct  dac_config config_dac;
    dac_get_config_defaults(&config_dac);
    dac_init(&dac_instance, DAC, &config_dac);
    dac_enable(&dac_instance);
}

void configure_dac_channel(void){
    struct dac_chan_config config_dac_chan;
    dac_chan_get_config_defaults(&config_dac_chan);
    dac_chan_set_config(&dac_instance, DAC_CHANNEL_0, &config_dac_chan);
    dac_chan_enable(&dac_instance, DAC_CHANNEL_0);
}

void configure_tc_callbacks(void){
    tc_register_callback(&tc_instance4, tc_callback_LEDBlink, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0);
    tc_enable_callback(&tc_instance4, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0);
}

int Calcul_Gabarit (int Etat , int Vpalier){

    switch(state)
    {
        //State Repos
        case Repos :
        Vconsigne = 0;
        if (Etat == Marche){
            if(Temps>=TRepos){
                Temps = 0;
                state = Acceleration;
                }else{
                Temps++;
            }
        }
        break;

        //State Accel
        case Acceleration :
        if(Temps >= Tmontee){
            Temps = 0;
            Vconsigne = Vpalier;
            state = VitesseConstante;
            }else{
            Temps++;
            Vconsigne = (Vpalier*Temps)/Tmontee;
        }
        break;

        //State Vconst
        case  VitesseConstante:
        if (Temps >= Tpalier){
            Temps = 0;
            state = Deceleration;
            }else{
            Temps++;
        }
        break;

        //State Decel
        case Deceleration :
        if(Temps >=TDescente){
            Vconsigne = 0;
            Temps = 0;
            state = Repos;
            }else{
            Temps++;
            Vconsigne = (Vpalier*(TDescente-Temps))/TDescente ;
        }
        break;
    }
    return Vconsigne;
}

void tc_callback_LEDBlink(struct tc_module *const module_inst){

    //Blink of the LED at 1HZ
    if(i ==500) {
        port_pin_toggle_output_level(LED_0_PIN);
        i = 0;
    }else{
        i++;
    }   

    int Vconsigne2 = Calcul_Gabarit(Etat,Vpalier);
    //Computation of Vconsigne every ms
    dac_chan_write(&dac_instance, DAC_CHANNEL_0, Vconsigne2*Resolution_DAC/VpalierMax);
    //Observation of Vconsigne (which is digital) using a DAC, on pin PA02
    tc_set_compare_value(&tc_instance6, TC_COMPARE_CAPTURE_CHANNEL_1, (Vconsigne2*PWM_CC0)/VpalierMax);
    //Every ms, we modify the duty cycle CC1 of TC6 using Vconsigne, scaled from 0 to 799
    //Output available on PB03
}

int main (void){
    system_init();

    configure_tc4();
    configure_tc_callbacks();

    configure_dac();
    configure_dac_channel();

    configure_tc6();    

    while (1) {}
}
```

Here is the pdf file generated from the LaTex code with the bug which appears in the top left corner :

[image: Pdf generated]

With a MWE I tried with inserting the line 9 to 64 and it looks like the root of the bug is from here :

[image: line 9 rootcause of the bug]

Using the numbers for the lines on the left applied to this "é" like it's a line.

Thanks for you help guys.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please help us help you and add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Could you please post your full code? It makes us easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post screen shots of code

Comment: @mv do you want my project ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I changed my source_file picture by the code

Comment: Nothing posted so far produces the posted output.  Please complete the code snippets to a minimal compilable document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I understand, I'll try to demonstrate the problem but it never happened before with my other source file code

Comment: @Cragfelt I did the MWE like recommanded

Comment: Thank you for posting this code.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't produce the extra character.  Have you tried with a different file of c code?

Comment: It looks like there is a bug when inserting the line 9. The character "é" is from the word commented "Définition"

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried on a different Tex engine and the bug is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `listingsutf8`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Ajout de code dans latex
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
%change the caption "Listing x" to "Algorithme x"
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{}
%And to color the code
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\lstdefinestyle{Langage_C}{
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        keywordstyle=\color{myblue}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{mygreen}\ttfamily,
        frame=single, 
        breaklines=true,
        numbers=left, 
        frame=single,
        extendedchars=true,
        inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
        breaklines,
        rulecolor=\color{black},
}
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[firstline=50,lastline=64,style = Langage_C, numbers = none]{4_main.c}

\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=64,style = Langage_C, numbers = none]{4_main.c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is `minted`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Ajout de code dans latex
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{fontsize=\footnotesize,breaklines,frame=single}
%And to color the code
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\begin{document}

\inputminted[firstline=50,lastline=64]{c}{main.c}

\inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=64]{c}{main.c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TwoplankAlex If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.